# Solving Recurrences in Loops

Tags: math, recursion, recurrence

I understand how to solve recurrence relations when they do not involve any additional looping i.e.:

```
int recursive_method(int n){
    if(n == 1){
       return 1;
    }
    some constant statement;
    recursive_method(n-1);

    return n; }
```

My problem comes when trying to solve recurrences inside of loops like the following:

```
int recursive_method(int n){
        if(n == 1){
           return 1;
        }
        for(int i = 1; i<n; i++){
           some constant statement;
           recursive_method(n-1);
        }
        return n; }
```

When trying to set up a recursive relation for the problem above would it look something like

```
T(n) = 1 if n<2; 
       sum(from i=1 to n){T(n-1) + c} if n>=2
```

So in other words the sum of the costs from 1 to n?
If not, how do I go about thinking about a problem like this?

Answer (score 0):

The expression you have for T(n) in the recursive case is right, but it can be significantly simplified. In particular, notice that the work done in the sum is independent of the summation index, so you can rewrite

> sum from i=1 to n { T(n-1) + c }

as

> nT(n - 1) + cn

So you'll end up with

> T(n) = 1 (if n ≤ 1)
>
> T(n) = nT(n - 1) + cn (otherwise)